# angular-ui-calendar "loading" loader spinner on click of month change button when events are loading

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am making an application using ionic frameWork,
Actually I have static calendar with events in ui-calendar, All events loads perfectly, but it is very slow to load, as there are lots events,because of that it is actually slow,So there is no issue if it takes small time to load events when month is changed,

The idea I have chosen is to add the loader(Spinner icon) when it starts loading the events when month is rendered, In order to achieve that, i got different ideas.
I have followed this [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HyNUq2?p=preview) which is fulfilling my need exactly what I want.

At the time of implementing

`loading:function(isLoading, view){
      alert("is loading" + isLoading);
    }`

does not enter this `loading:` which will help me show spinner(loader) to be visible when "isLoading" is true and hide when "isLoading" is false.

This will exactly help me to get loader on event loading, but this code is ignored and i cannot get the alert warning,I am not getting where I am going wrong here.

my controller code is:

```
 .controller('CalTabCtrl', function($scope ,$timeout,$ionicLoading,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$ionicModal, $ionicPopup,$sce) 
   {                                                                                       $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
        $scope.events = [
  {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
  {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
  {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
  {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
  {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
  {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
];
        $scope.calOptions = {
          editable: true,
          lang:'hi',
          height: ($(window).height()) - ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 1000)),
          header : {
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'title,today',
          right: 'next'
          },
          eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){  
            var selectedDate=calEvent.start.format('Do MMMM YYYY,dddd');
            var eventTitle=calEvent.title;
            var description=calEvent.description;
               $scope.safeApply(function()
               {
                 $scope.eventModal(selectedDate,eventTitle,description)
               });
             },
             eventRender: function (event, element) {
                              // $scope.loading();
             element.find('span.fc-title').html(element.find('span.fc-title').text()); 

             },
             loading:function(isLoading, view){
                   alert("is loading " + isLoading);
          },

           };
     /* event sources array*/
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
          })
```

In above code only the 'loading:' is not executed, Ther eis no alert when load starts and load complete, which will help me to add loader(spinner) there.

Any type of suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. The fullCalendar parameter `loading` is related with fetching the events via AJAX, i.e., with `events` (as a json feed): http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/, but you are not loading the events in the code above. On the other hand, there is no `$scope.loading()` (it is `$scope.calOptions.loading()`, if you want to call it directly).

Comment: I have just now edited the code with events added to eventSource[]; My main problem is I am not getting why the alert inside the loading fuction doesnot popup,

Comment: See my longer answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the Plunker demo, the fullCalendar options look like this:

[image: Plunker demo]

The `eventSources` has two elements. The latter with an URL causes an Ajax call, and it is this source that makes `loading()` to be called.

It is easy to verify that this is the case: just add `options.eventSources.length = 1;` above the `debugger;` line. This drops the 'Ajax' event source off and `loading()` is not called anymore.

So, my guess is that you just do not have an Ajax-based event source.

UPDATE:

I made a version of my own of the [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIi4Mf?p=preview), demonstrating how the notificator can be moved from loading to rendering.

calendarController.js: `$scope.rendering` added, `$scope.uiConfig.loading` removed, `$scope.uiConfig.eventAfterAllRender` added, `$scope.eventSource` removed from `$scope.eventSources`.

uiCalendarDirective.js: `scope.rendering` added (an ugly duplication), `scope.init` modified to make a call to `scope.rendering`.

UPDATE 2:

An improved version of the [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aQvX9k?p=preview) that moves the first notification to be shown before rendering:

```
viewRender: function () {
    $scope.rendering(true);
},
eventAfterAllRender: function () {
    $scope.rendering(false);
}
```

Update `init`as well:

```
scope.init = function() {
    scope.calendar.fullCalendar(options);
};
```

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct, I do not have events in a json format so there is no ajax call there and because of that am not getting the loading call back,So I have lot of events in events variable but not in json format,actually I am new to fullCalendar,Can you please guide me how do I put the loader at the time of loading events Or can you tell how do I call all the events which I currently have. I dont know how to set and get the events using json. This app is static read only app in which there is no use of internet, Events are just for read only.

Comment: If there are so many events that even the rendering of the events requires a notificator, then I would challenge whether it makes sense to hold such a huge number of events in JavaScript. Where is this data being read from? If you do not want to change that, then you could try to add the notificator before initializing the fullCalendar, and remove it in `eventAfterAllRender` event handler. If that works, then you need to consider additionally, how the notificator will be applied when the contents are re-rendered.

Comment: Using array for the events, Is there ant way to get the load events? Or can u please give me an idea how to go with static json file withing the project as this is an android app so want to keep the events static(Read only).Or do have any idea how to catch the fullcalendar.js before initializing?

Comment: Why is the event rendering now so slow that it requires a notificator? The events array must be huge, what is the length of it? Where does the application read this data from and how?

Comment: there are 2 events per day ,so 730 events in one year and at the time of loading it loads 60 event for a month,i have created an array events[]  and pushing the events in $scope.eventSources.

Comment: And yes because of your i got to know that the loading: executes when there is a json call. Now the option is i have get tha handler when fullcalendar.js loads which will help me add the loader there and hide loader at eventAfterAllRendered. Dont how to catch fullCalendar.js before loading.If u have any idea it would be really very helpfull here.

Comment: I updated the answer to contain an example, how the notificator can be moved from loading to rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99062/discussion-between-ajit-hogade-and-masa).